# Delete multiple google drive files that are unorganized / orphaned

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I wanted to remove several thousand files in a Google Drive folder.  I deleted the folder, which many in the community know (but I didn't) leaves the files present but orphaned. I can list the files via "is:unorganized  owner:me" but can't select more than a few hundred at a time to (slowly) delete.

Is there a script that will search for and delete these, and only these, files?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the files searched with `is:unorganized owner:me` and want to delete the files.
- You want to reduce the process cost of this process.

### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, the files cannot be directly retrieved by searching `is:unorganized owner:me` with Drive API and Drive service. So as the current workaround, I would like to suggest the following flow.

1. Retrieve the file list of all files in the Google Drive. In this case, `'me' in owners and trashed = false` is used as the search query. The method of "Files: list" of Drive API is used for this.
2. Retrieve the file list of files which have no parent folder using a script.

   - By above flow 1 and 2, the search of `is:unorganized owner:me` can be achieved using a script.
3. Move the files to the trash box using the retrieved file list using the method of "Files: update" of Drive API.

   - In this case, the files are not directly deleted. Because when the files are directly deleted, I thought that this situation is very dangerous. Of course, the files can be also directly deleted using the method of "Files: delete" of Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete)
   - From your question, I thought that there might be a lot of files you want to delete. So in this answer, I would like to suggest to use the batch requests.

When above flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

### IMPORTANT: PLEASE BE CAREFUL!

- **When you use this sample script, please be careful this. I would like to recommend the following flow for using this script.**

  1. Retrieve the file list of `is:unorganized owner:me` and check whether all files of the file list are the files you want to delete.

     - You can retrieve the file list using `const fileList = getFileList(token);` in `main()` function.
  2. When you could completely confirm that all files of the file list are the files you want to delete, please use `const res = moveFilesToTrashBox(token, fileList);`. By this, the files of file list are moved to the trash box.
  3. Please confirm the trash box. When the files you don't want to delete are included, please restore them.

### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). And please run `main()` function.

```
// Move the files in the file list to the trash box.
function moveFilesToTrashBox(token, fileList) {
  const limit = 100;
  const split = Math.ceil(fileList.length / limit);
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    const boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    const payload = fileList.splice(0, limit).reduce((s, {id}, i, a) => s += "Content-Type: application/http\r\n" +
    "Content-ID: " + i + "\r\n\r\n" +
    "PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + id + "\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n" +
    JSON.stringify({trashed: true}) + "\r\n" +
    "--" + boundary + (i == a.length - 1 ? "--" : "") + "\r\n" , "--" + boundary + "\r\n");
    const params = {
      method: "post",
      contentType: "multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary,
      payload: payload,
      headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + token},
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };
    const r = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3", params);
    res.push(r.getContentText());
  }
  return res;
}

// Retrieve the file list by searching with "is:unorganized owner:me".
function getFileList(token) {
  const fields = decodeURIComponent("nextPageToken,files(name,id,mimeType,parents)");
  const q = decodeURIComponent("'me' in owners and trashed = false");
  let allFiles = [];
  let pageToken = "";
  do {
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&fields=${fields}&q=${q}&pageToken=${pageToken}`,
      { headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } }
    );
    const obj = JSON.parse(res);
    allFiles = allFiles.concat(obj.files);
    pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  return allFiles.filter(({ parents }) => !parents);  
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  
  // Retrieve the file list of all files in the Google Drive.
  const fileList = getFileList(token);
  console.log(fileList.length);
  console.log(fileList);
  
  // Move the files to the trash box using the retrieved file list.
  // When you could completely confirm that all files of the file list are the files you want to delete, please use the below script.
  // const res = moveFilesToTrashBox(token, fileList);
  // console.log(res);


  // DriveApp.createFile(); // This is used for automatically adding a scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".
}
```

### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)
- [Batch request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch)

Comment: Many thanks for the very complete reply. I've never written gs before; apologies for trivial questions.  I ran main, but I can't find the file list.  I did view/logs, but that output was too large and was truncated. How do I verify the filelist is correct?  Tnx

Comment: I later realized this may already be writing to the log. The first entry shows the length is 4379, but due to truncation, only 73 files are mentioned. Can the script write to a file that won't get truncated? Thank you

Comment: @murspieg Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When you want to see the file list of a lot of files, how about putting `DriveApp.createFile("filelist.txt", JSON.stringify(fileList));` after the line of `const fileList = getFileList(token);`? By this, the file list can be retrieved as a file of `filelist.txt`. The file is created to the root folder. If this was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Worked well.  The filelist was a single long line; in Linux I had to pipe to sed 's/{/\^J{/g' to separate the lines.  If you use this advice for others, I'd suggest adding a function to add \n and or \r's.  Again, thank you so much

Comment: @murspieg Thank you for replying. For example, when `DriveApp.createFile("filelist.txt", JSON.stringify(fileList));` is modified to `DriveApp.createFile("filelist.txt", JSON.stringify(fileList, null, "  "));`, the readability of data in the file might become high. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)